# Can the Thai government legally ban Thai citizens from entering Thailand?

Tags: travel, thailand

I read on https://bangkokpost.com/thailand/general/1891790/govt-temporarily-blocks-all-travel that the Thai government will temporarily block all inbound travel. Can the Thai government legally ban Thais from entering Thailand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Section 34 of Constitution of the Kingdom of Thailand [says](http://web.krisdika.go.th/data/outsitedata/outsite21/file/Constitution_of_the_Kingdom_of_Thailand.pdf) (highlight mine):

> […] No  person  of  Thai  nationality  shall  be  deported  **or  prohibited  from  entering** the Kingdom.

The referenced document points to the most recent [2017 Constitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitution_of_Thailand#2017_Constitution).

So the naive answer is **No,** however some legal gap may be found by the Constitutional Court (Section 27).

More specifically, it would depend on the legal equivalence of terms "Thai citizens" and "person of Thai nationality".

Comment: There may also be, as in most countries, the possibility that a temporary prohibition for reasons of public health might somehow be permissible in the face of the constitutional provision against such a prohibition.  I doubt that there's any line of reasoning in which "person of Thai nationality" would not include Thai citizens.

Comment: I agree with @phoog that "person of Thai nationality" is either equivalent to or broader than the term "Thai citizen". Often constitutional provisions that are facially absolute are subject to implied exceptions, however.

Comment: There's a difference between 'Denying Entry' and 'Delaying Entry'. In a quarantine period, you'll be *eventually* admitted.